# Are passive piezo speaker more reliable than magnetic ones?

Tags: speakers, piezo-buzzer

I'm going to use sound notification in my desing (just beeping). My buzzer needs to be suited for cold ambient conditions (up to 0 celcius degrees), high humidity and shocks. Which buzzer type will be more aproperiate? Is it true that piezo buzzers are more reliable?

Comment: Try looking for them on the normal distributor sites you use and making comparisons of their respective data sheets. Your title talks about reliability but your question talks about specifications and limits. The two can be largely unrelated.

Comment: Do you mean piezo speaker? Piezo buzzers beep when DC power supply is applied. The piezo speaker you drive yourself with a tone like a normal speaker. Which one you want?

Comment: I mean speaker.

Comment: 0-degrees C is not really very "cold" for either of those technologies.   They should both be fine.  Piezo's have an advantage of using far less energy, so if your product is battery operated, that might be an advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your question is in general terms, with no specific numbers such as required lifetime, humidity levels, shock levels, etc. , one can only answer in general terms. Magnetic (voice coil) speakers are reliable (again, no numbers) but the vibrating membrane poses a potential fault problem since it is fragile compared to a piezo speaker which has none. However piezo materials are relatively brittle and can shatter or crack when exposed to shock. Also note that a magnetic speaker probably won't fail completely even if the membrane tears but a piezo speaker will stop working if it shatters.